# How to show that $\lfloor n/1\rfloor+\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+....+\lfloor n/n\rfloor+\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$ is even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

> Let $n$ is a natural number. Prove that $$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+....+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{n}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor$$
>   is **even**.

I used induction and the inequality $$x-1<\lfloor{x}\rfloor\le{x}$$ to prove it.

Is there any other, nicer way to do it?

Comment: Induction is a good way to go and the inequality you used is all we have about the floor function, so what could be a better way?

Comment: [A duplicate of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698562/to-prove-that-n-1-n-2n-3-dots-n-n-sqrtn-is-even) was asked later.  You might find my answer to that question useful.

Comment: @David +1. Truly remarkable answer by you in that post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let 
$$S = \{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2\mid ab\le n\,\} $$
and $$ T=\{\,(a,a)\in\mathbb N^2\mid a^2\le n\,\}.$$
Then
$$ |S|=\sum_{b\ge 1}|\{\,a\in\mathbb N\mid a\le\tfrac nb\,\}|=\sum_{b\ge 1}\lfloor \tfrac nb\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac n1\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor+\ldots +\left\lfloor \frac nn\right \rfloor$$
and $$ |T|=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor.$$
The map $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$ is a fixedpoint-free involution of $S\setminus T$, hence 
$|S\setminus T|$ is even. Since 
$$ \left\lfloor \frac n1\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor+\ldots +\left\lfloor \frac nn\right \rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor = |S\setminus T|+2|T|$$
we are done.