# To prove that $ [n/1]+ [n/2]+[n/3]+\dots +[n/n]+[\sqrt{n}]$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. How do you prove that

$$ \lfloor n/1 \rfloor+ \lfloor n/2\rfloor+ \lfloor n/3\rfloor+\dots +\lfloor n/n]+\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$$

is even? Thanks.

Comment: Use $\large\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ instead of $\large\left[x\right]$. The $\large\tt LaTeX$ code is $\large\verb=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=$

Comment: $[x]$ is also OK.  Maybe a bit out of date.  No real need to change.

Comment: Guys if it's any help, I checked the given expression on a program, it seems to evaluate to 2n. Ideas?

Comment: @Sabyasachi For $n=4$ it is $10$ not $2\times 4$

Comment: Oops no, that is only valid up until $n=3$. The $\lfloor  x\rfloor$ function is weird.

Comment: Okay, anyway here's the list. $[2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 26, 30, 32, 38, 40, 44, 48, 54, 56, 62, 64, 70, 74, 78, 80, 88, 92, 96, 100, 106, 108, 116, 118, 124, 128, 132, 136, 146, 148, 152, 156, 164, 166, 174, 176, 182, 188, 192, 194, 204, 208, 214, 218, 224, 226, 234, 238, 246, 250, 254, 256, 268, 270, 274, 280, 288, 292, 300, 302, 308, 312, 320, 322, 334, 336, 340, 346, 352, 356, 364, 366, 376, 382, 386, 388, 400, 404, 408, 412, 420, 422, 434, 438, 444, 448, 452, 456, 468, 470, 476, 482]$ , $n=1 \text{to} 99$

Comment: there does seem to be a pattern of consecutive even numbers. mysterious disappearances.

Comment: This is question 2 from this year's Indian National Mathematical Olympiad, see http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/subjects/mathematics/previous-question-papers-and-solutions (INMO 2014). This has been asked before on MSE but I can't find the link.

Comment: Just to connect this with the earliest question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661010/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is a sketch of an argument, see if you can generalise and fill in the details.  We illustrate the sum
$$\Bigl[\frac{n}{1}\Bigr]+\Bigl[\frac{n}{2}\Bigr]+\cdots+\Bigl[\frac{n}{n}\Bigr]$$
by a pattern of dots, where the number of dots in column $j$ is equal to $[n/j]$.  If say $n=6$ it will look like this,
$$\matrix{\bullet\cr \bullet\cr \bullet\cr \bullet&\bullet\cr
  \bullet&\bullet&\bullet\cr \bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\cr}$$
and for future reference we label the rows and columns as shown:
$$\matrix{6&\bullet\cr 5&\bullet\cr 4&\bullet\cr 3&\bullet&\bullet\cr
  2&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\cr
  1&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\cr
  &1&2&3&4&5&6\cr}$$

If you draw a few more examples it seems clear that the pattern is symmetric about the diagonal.  To show that this is in fact true, note that there is a dot in row $i$, column $j$ if and only if
$$i\le\frac{n}{j}\ ,$$
and this is the same as saying that there is a dot in row $j$, column $i$.  Now ignore the dots on the diagonal, for example,
$$\matrix{\bullet\cr \bullet\cr \bullet\cr \bullet&\bullet\cr
  \bullet&\circ&\bullet\cr \circ&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\cr}$$
By symmetry, the remaining dots are even in number.

Now how many dots are there on the diagonal?  There is a dot at $(i,i)$ if and only if $i\le n/i$, if and only if $i^2\le n$, if and only if $i\le[\sqrt n]$.  So the number of dots on the diagonal is $[\sqrt n]$.  Putting all this together shows that the number in the problem is even.

Comment: this is inspired.

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(n)$ be the sum. It is useful to rewrite it as

$$ f(n) = [\sqrt{n}] + \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} [n/k] $$

What is $f(n) - f(n-1)$? The differences in the two formulas are:

- Each of the terms $[n/k]$ is one larger than $[(n-1)/k]$ if and only if $k | n$. (this includes $k=n$)
- If $n$ is a perfect square, then $[\sqrt{n}]$ is one larger than $[\sqrt{n-1}]$.

The effect of the first bullet adds $1$ for every factor of $n$. Most numbers have an even number of factors (e.g. if $x$ divides $n$, then so does $n/x$). The only exceptions are the perfect squares, which have an odd number of factors, but those are precisely the times when the second bullet point adds $1$.

Thus, $f(n) - f(n-1)$ is always even.

Comment: I am having trouble I am having trouble understanding your first bullet point. I would understand it if it said “Each of the terms $[n/k]$ where $k$ is one larger than $[(n-1)/k]$”, but the $k|n$ is confusing me.  I understand $k|n$ as a proposition, not as an arithmetic term.  What did you mean by that?

Comment: @MJD: I assert that $[n/k] = [(n-1)/k]$ if and only if $k$ does not divide $n$. Otherwise $[n/k] = [(n-1)/k] + 1$.

Comment: So you meant “Where $k|n$, each of the terms $[n/k]$ is one larger than $[(n-1)/k]$?”

Comment: @MJD: Ah, I see the problem. I've inserted two commas to help with parsing. Bah, but that makes the phrasing awkward too. I need to reorganize that statement.