# INMO Problem with even function proof.

Tags: number-theory, induction, contest-math

> Let $n$ be a natural number. Show that
>   $$\left[ \frac{n}{1} \right ] + \left[ \frac{n}{2} \right ] + \left[ \frac{n}{3} \right ] + \cdots + \left[ \frac{n}{n} \right ] + [\sqrt{n}]$$ is even. Here $[x]$ means the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Let $$f(n) = [\sqrt{n}] + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{n}{k} \right]$$

$$f(1) = [1] + [1] = 2 \checkmark$$

The statement for $f(n+1)$ is to be proved:

$$f(n+1) = [\sqrt{n+1}] + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left[\frac{n+1}{k} \right]$$

I just need some hints from now?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661010) and several linked questions for various proofs.

Comment: @barto Isn't a "can I have hint" question very different from a "Give me the answer" question? Or does MSE consider these duplicates of each other?

Comment: Ah yes, true. This has been discussed on meta [multiple times](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19043). Personally, I prefer not to make a distinction. While I appreciate user's efforts to answer these questions with much sympathy for the OP's personal wishes, I think the most healthy for the community is to have as little duplicates as possible. But we'd better not continue this in the comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove by induction.

When is $ \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor \neq \lfloor \frac{n+1}{k} \rfloor $?
When they are not equal, what is the difference of these 2 terms?

Ans: The terms are different if there exists some integer $i$ such that $ \frac{n}{k} < i \leq \frac{ n+1}{k}$. Multiplying throughout by $k$, we get $ n < ik \leq n+1$. Since $n$, $n+1$ are consecutive integers, this then implies that $ik = n+1$, or that $k$ is a divisor of $n+1$.
Thus, this term increases by 1 if $k \mid n+1$. Otherwise, it stays constant.

---

Hence, letting $ g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$, we get that

$$g(n+1) - g(n) = \text{ number of divisors of } n$$

Comment: Suppose $k=2$. Let the floor just be shown by $[]$

For $n = 0, 1$ **the first one, ** then it is: $$[0], [1/2] = 0$$

**the second one** for $n=0, 1$ it is: $$[1/2] = 0, [1] = 1$$ So it is unequal at $n= 1$. The difference is $(2) - (1) = 1$ where (2) is the second equation.

Comment: @INMO Yes, they are also different at $\lfloor \frac{2}{2} \rfloor$ because this is a new term that was introduced. More generally, can you provide a classification for when this changes? (An example of a potential classification is "the number changes when $k$ has the same parity as $n+1$" or "the number changes every time")

Comment: Mmmmmmm.I don't see a specific pattern. BUt how would that help anyway?

Comment: Whenever $n$ is odd they are different I believe?

Comment: @INMO Note: You should not accept an answer that you don't really understand. The pattern is "the terms are different when $k$ divides $n+1$. In this case, the value increases by exactly 1". This tells you that the sum of terms $ \lfloor  \frac{n+1}{k} \rfloor$ increases by the value of the number of divisors of $n+1$, IE $d(n+1)$ in Brian's solution below.

Comment: How do you observe that? It doesnt seem outright to me?

Comment: $$g(n+1) - g(n) = 1$$ mostly, so $n$ only has $1$ divisor?

Comment: @INMO We must have $ \frac{n}{k} < i \leq \frac{n+1}{k}$ in order for the terms to be different. This implies that $ n < ik \leq n+1$. And then .... (can you continue?)

Comment: @INMO No, each integer has at least 2 divisors, namely 1 and itself. For primes $p$, we have $d(p) = 2$. But for composite numbers, $d(p) > 2$. For example, $ d(4) = 3, d(6) = 4 $.

Comment: It seems a lot like the inequality suggests: $[ik] = n$

Comment: Well, use the fact that $ (n+1) - n $ = 1 to conclude that if $ n < ik \leq n+1 $, then we must have $ik = n+1$, or that $k$ divides $n+1$.

Comment: $n < ik \le n + (n+1) - n$$ But that doesnt help

Answer (score 3):

HINT: One way is to prove by induction on $n$ that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^nd(k)\;,$$

where $d(k)$ is the number of (positive) divisors of $k$. For what values of $n$ does this change parity?

Comment: +1 While I agree that is the underlying idea to the problem, writing it up this way makes it appear as if "Oh, I must know this special fact to solve this problem."

Comment: @Calvin: True; I actually did know it and didn’t think about pointing specifically at what makes it work. On that score your hint (+1) may prove more helpful.