# Sum of floor functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For a positive integer $n$, let
$$\def\fl#1{\left\lfloor\frac n{#1}\right\rfloor}f(n)=\fl 1+\fl2+\fl3+\cdots+\fl n.$$
Find $f(1,000,000)−f(999,999)$. I know the changes in the floors will take place when the denominator is a factor of the numerator. But it is a long process. Is a simpler process available.

Comment: Have you tried calculating a simpler version of the same thing, say $f(10)-f(9)$, or $f(100)-f(99)$? That might give you some ideas that you could scale up to solve the $f(1000000)$ problem.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661010) (Some of the linked questions there have answers solving your question too.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider what happens to a specific summand in the one case compared to the other:

$\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ compared to $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\rfloor$

One of two things will be true.  Either $n\equiv 0\mod k$ or you will have that $n\equiv r\mod k$ with $1\leq r<k$

If $n\equiv r\mod k$ (i.e. there is a positive remainder), then it follows that $\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\rfloor$

Else, with $n\equiv 0\mod k$ you have $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor = \lfloor\frac{n-1}{k}\rfloor + 1$

Since $n\equiv 0\mod k$ implies that $k$ is a factor of $n$, it should quickly follow that $f(n)-f(n-1) = d(n)$ where $d(n)$ counts the number of factors of $n$.

The number of factors of 1,000,000 can be found via multiplication principle.  $1,000,000=10^6 = 2^65^6$.  Each *different* factor will be of the form $2^a5^b$, there are 7 choices for $a$ and 7 choices for $b$, hence there are 49 factors.

$f(1,000,000)-f(999,999) = 49$

Comment: Are you sure 36 is correct. I don't feel it is correct. Please just check it.

Comment: There are _seven_ choices of exponent ranging from $0$ to $6$. Other than that I agree with this method. Try the answer $49$.

Comment: oh, indeed @DavidK  My mistake there.  Thanks for catching that.